# Running a python code within a python script

Tags: python

I want to do following. Script has some python code as a string (saved in a variable) and is it possible to run that code ?

Well, I know one way, writing that string to a file & running it, but I don't want that. Without creating any extra file, is it possible to run it ?

Here is a example :

let's assume my python file has following content

```
#this is a main python file
content = ''' print 'hello!'
                   print 'this is from sub python code' '''
print 'from main python'
```

The content string has a python code & I want to run it. Is it possible ?

Hope I am clear. Thank you !

Comment: @Blender - Thank you editing. I posted this from a mobile & before I could realize, you had it edited. :)

Comment: Can you tell us why there's a string with code in it?  Why not just change the string to be a function?  If it's data you read from somewhere else, you are opening yourself to a world of hurt if you don't trust the source.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder - Oops, I didn't get that idea. But how do I change string to a function, without writing to a another file ?

I am not reading data from any untrusted source. I am just experimenting. And thanks for the warning, I will be careful.

Comment: @AshRj - Yup, that's the one ! Will check out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll say this up front: This is a terrible idea, and depending on the source of the string a serious security risk.

That disclaimer out of the way, python has an exec function that executes a string containing python code. For example:

```
exec("print 2+2")
```

Edit: I originally used eval in my answer, which is useful for evaluating individual expressions, while exec can be used for more general execution of arbitrary python code in a string.

Relevant docs:

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: I am not reading data from any untrusted source. I am just experimenting. And thanks for the warning, I will be careful.

Can eval run full python code ? with import libraries & stuff ? 

Thanks for replying !

Comment: So I actually was a little rusty on the exact mechanics of eval, and exec would be more appropriate for that sort of thing. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Okay, turns eval doesn't work out for statements & its only for expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use `eval`:

```
eval(content)
```

And that will do what you want, however it's not recommended, especially if someone else controls the content of `content` - it's not too hard to hack into your system if you have `eval`

Comment: I am not reading data from any untrusted source. I am just experimenting. And thanks for the warning, I will be careful.

Thank you for replying !

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with exec method as per documentation that should do

exec "print 'Hello, World!'"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the code you are trying to execute, you may use `eval()` or `exec`. There are several differences between these two options:

1. `eval()` does what it should: it evaluates an expression and returns a value, not executes code. That means you may call functions, do some arithmetic, even use list comprehensions, generators or lambdas, but not execute python statements that aren't expressions (e.g. `if`, `for`, `print` in Python 2; however, in Python 3 `print` is a function and is ok).
2. `eval()` accepts more parameters than just a string. It gets `locals` and `globals`, two dictionaries, defining the scope environment. You may make evaluation nearly (though not really) safe for untrusted strings if you fill and pass these dictionaries to `eval()`. Probably, you may even redefine builtins by properly setting `__builtins__` in globals. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval
3. `exec` also accepts globals and locals. See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec . And it may execute everything. And it is virtually impossible to make it even relatively safe.